# replacing a word with a sentence in perl script

Tags: perl

Is there a way we can replace a word with a complete sentence in perl

I know there is a option

```
perl -pi-back -e 's/ACTUAL_WORD/EXPECTED_WORD/g;' inputfile.txt
```

This replaces only word to a word. My requirement is to replace below mentioned ACTUAL_WORD with EXPECTED_SENTENCE.

```
ACTUAL_WORD: test
EXPECTED_SENTENCE: this if for sandbox
```

UPDATED ISSUE
I am trying to replace the word with Sentence with in a perl script

system("perl -pi-back -e 's/\$SHELL/genidasack.py -v --alignment=mips64 -a -s \$WORKSPACE/dbgen/ose_signals_ADA.sdt -o \$WORKSPACE/\$Product//g;' ~/.local/bin/envsetup_sack.py");

and i get following error

**Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/$SHELL/genidasack.py -v --alignment=mips64 -a -s $WORKSPACE/dbgen"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/$SHELL/genidasack.py -v --alignment=mips64 -a -s $WORKSPACE/dbgen"
Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.**

i am completely lost what is causing this error; when i run the command manually everything works fine :(

Comment: Have you considered `s/ACTUAL_WORD/EXPECTED_SENTENCE/g`?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to perform the substitution with the sentence and see what happens. You can leave out the `-i-back` option while testing, so the file is not changed.

Comment: Trying things out is often a faster approach than asking the internet. But Perl knows nothing about words or sentences, it only understands strings of characters.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Just put spaces in `EXPECTED_WORD`.

```
perl -pi-back -e 's/ACTUAL_WORD/The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog/g;' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear in my previous question; i have updated the question